# find a spanning set of F(D)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to understand how to even tackle this problem. Apparent it is a situation in which you need to find a spanning set of all real-valued functions such that this set is defined on a finite domain. Let D = {a,b,c,d} where a,b,c,d are natural numbers; find a spanning set of F(D).

Now, I have read a similar question, but the answers to it were so ambiguous and unclear that I did not get any of it. [How do you find the spanning set of real-valued functions with only it's finite domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370025/how-do-you-find-the-spanning-set-of-real-valued-functions-with-only-its-finite)

I know how to find a spanning set for polynomials but here F(D) is for all possible functions that maps D to $\ R $.

My intuition tells me that it would be something along the lines of Span{F(1),F(2),F(3),F(4)}, but I have no idea why exactly and how to prove that if it would be true and something tells me that this intuition is most probably false anyways.

A little bit of help would be greatly appreciated here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define $f_a(x)=1 \text{ if } x=a, 0$ otherwise.  Use analogous definitions for $f_b, f_c, f_d$.

Any function is completely specified by its value on all elements of its domain.  If the domain is finite (as it is in this case), that means you can completely specify the function by simply listing its values at each element of the domain.

So you should be able to demonstrate that $\{f_a, f_b, f_c, f_d \}$ is a linearly independent set that spans $F(D)$.

Comment: thanks! which topic should I be looking for in a textbook for instance to get more detail on this subject?

Comment: Like I don't even know why it is f(x) = 1 at x=a and 0 otherwise? Is this like a special theorem?

Comment: No.  You can define a function any way you'd like.  I'm suggesting a particularly useful set of functions for this problem.